# Bash for python3 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I wrote a program on a **Raspberry Pi** using **Python 3**. I want to create a **bash file**, like this the future user will just have to launch `MyScirpt.sh` to execute my python script.

So I wrote on `MyScript.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
python3 /home/pi/Documents/MyFolder/MyScript.py
```

After this, I make this file executable using:

```
chmod u+x MyScript.sh
```

But it seems to be not enough. Can you help me to understand what I missed ?

Obvisouly, if I go in `/home/pi/Documents/MyFolder` and, in a terminal, execute `python3 MyScript.py`, it is working.

Comment: What does "but it seems to be not enough" mean? Do you get an error msg?

Comment: To run your shell script remove the first line (the one starting with  `#!`). A better way is to write `#!/usr/bin/env python3` in your **python** script (MyScript.py) and making that script executable. The reason is: you are telling the system with the shebang which interpreter to use. You are trying to run a bash script using python, and they do not share the same syntax.

Comment: @matteo, if I delete the first line, nothing happens when I Execute. Can you tell me more about your second solution ?

Comment: If you made the script executable it must work. Without a shebang the default interpreter is the console interpreter (usually bash/dash). From your comment in another answer I suspect that your script is not where you are thinking. Are you sure about the script path? Are you sure you have no blank space in directory names?

Comment: The goal is having a shofrtcut on the desktop which call the program on a specific folder. So if I make my python script executable, I lost this advantage. Regarding the folder, I copy/paste from a linux explorer the path so I can't be wrong.

Comment: Why do you lose the advantage? That's not true. Make a symbolic link on your desktop and you are good to go, with less disk occupied. **If the path contains blank spaces** your copy and paste does not work, without quotes around the path (e.g. `python3 "/home/pi/My Folder/MyScript.py"`).

Comment: If the path contains blank spaces, the `cd`command will fail too no? Because it is not. I right click on the file, and choose `Copy path`and I have the original path of my bash file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166326/discussion-between-matteo-ragni-and-mathieu-gauquelin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I resolved the issue.

I deleted the first line of the bash file, so I just have the command `python3 /path/to/script.py`. I added the quotes `""` around the path of the script, and I deleted an invisible blank space at the end of the line that I didn't see.

And it is working. Thank you all for your help, because it guided me in finding the solution!

Answer (score 3):

You are using the shebang line for python 3 for your bash script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

The correct one for bash would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

In your python script you still need the upper one though.

Comment: Doing this, and executing with double-clicking, nothing happens.

Comment: Did you rename your python script with the .sh ending or are both scripts in the same folder?

Comment: Both in the same folder, the .py with my code, and the .sh which have to call the .py

Comment: When I do `Execute in terminal`, the terminal open and close immediately., without message on it. Do I have to add the line `#!/usr/bin/env python3`in all the python files call by my main script ?

Comment: Yep. At least I think / do so. What puzzles me is that you said, when you start the python script from the terminal it seems to work ...

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to run the script? You probably need to specify the path, e.g. from the local directory

```
./MyScript.sh
```

EDIT: It's definitely the shebang path -I'd missed that. It should be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

- i.e. you're telling the script to launch bash, then the next line tells it to launch python and run the script.

Comment: Double-cliking on it and, in the four choice `Execute/Execute in Terminal/Open/Cancel`, choosing `Execute`

Comment: Try Execute in Terminal